# AudioKit's FFTTap gives zeroes on physical device when reinitiated

Tags: audiokit

I am trying to create an app that analyzes FFT streams and compares an original to a subsequent stream. To do this, I need to be able to shut down and reinitiate the stream.

On the simulator this works without a problem. On a physical device (iPad 12.9 1st gen) only the first session gives valid data, whereas starting with the second I get only zeros.

I created a sample Xcode project that demonstrated the issue. It can be downloaded from here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rR2zWPREwXbXfZFocubwMgQ8SyFrXt2V/view?usp=sharing

Here is the ViewController's code:

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var toggleLearn: UIButton!

    var listenTimer : Timer?

    let mic = AKMicrophone()

    var compressor = AKCompressor()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func listen() {

        compressor.start()
        compressor = AKCompressor(mic)

        if let inputs = AudioKit.inputDevices {
            do {
                try AudioKit.setInputDevice(inputs[0])
            } catch {
                print ("Could not set audio inputs: \(error)")
            }
            do {
                try mic.setDevice(inputs[0])
            } catch {
                print ("Could not set the audio input device to the AKMic: \(error)")
            }
        }

        AudioKit.output = AKBooster(compressor, gain: 0)

        if !AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
            do {
                try AudioKit.start()
            } catch {
                print ("Could not start AudioKit: \(error)")
            }
        }

        compressor.threshold = 3
        compressor.headRoom = 3
        compressor.masterGain = 1
        compressor.attackDuration = 0.001
        compressor.releaseDuration = 0.01

        mic.start()

        let fft = AKFFTTap(compressor)

        if listenTimer == nil {
            listenTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.08, repeats: true, block: { _ in

                let i = fft.fftData

                print (i[100...200])

            })
        }
    }

    @IBAction func learnPage(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
            if listenTimer != nil {
                listenTimer?.invalidate()
                listenTimer = nil
            }
            mic.stop()
            compressor.stop()
            try! AudioKit.stop()

            toggleLearn.setTitle("Listen", for: .normal)
        } else {
            toggleLearn.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
            listen()
        }
    }
}
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you be open to a solution that changed the way you do things? I just think its a bad idea to be starting and stopping AudioKit with a button like this.

Comment: The audio analysis is just one part of the planned app. I need to be able to call the analysis function multiple times. I am open to any solution that would allow me to do that without significant performance impact. When I tried reassigning the fft variable without stopping AudioKit, the app crashed. Thank you so much for the quick response and the tremendous work!

Answer (score 1):

I did find a very ugly hack, for the time being:

1. Edit the public init of the AKFFTTap.swift file, and add another parameter to it, that would remove the tap:

   ```
   public init(_ input: AKNode, activate: Bool) {
       super.init()

       if activate == true {

           fft = EZAudioFFT(maximumBufferSize: vDSP_Length(bufferSize), sampleRate: Float(AKSettings.sampleRate), delegate: self)
           input.avAudioNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: bufferSize, format: AudioKit.format) { [weak self] (buffer, time) -> Void in
               guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
               buffer.frameLength = strongSelf.bufferSize
               let offset = Int(buffer.frameCapacity - buffer.frameLength)
               let tail = buffer.floatChannelData?[0]
               strongSelf.fft!.computeFFT(withBuffer: &tail![offset],
                                      withBufferSize: strongSelf.bufferSize)
           }

       } else {

           input.avAudioNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
       }
   }
   ```
2. When you first call the tap, remember to add the new parameter:

   ```
   let fft = AKFFTTap(compressor, activate: true)
   ```
3. In the code that deallocates AudioKit's resources, use the parameter to remove the tap:

   ```
   func stopListening() {
       // The first block nullifies the timer from my example above. Not necessary unless you use the timer.
       if listenTimer != nil {
           listenTimer?.invalidate()
           listenTimer = nil
       }
       if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
           mic.stop()
           compressor.stop()

           let _ = AKFFTTap(compressor, activate: false)
       }
   }
   ```

This hack messes up the chain established by AudioKit, and if you stop and restart AudioKit, you'll get very weird behavior (in my case - my dummy output became very not-dummy). However, if you repeat all the setup without stopping AudioKit, the result holds. That means, in the case of the code in my original question, recalling the listen() function.